# Can I use search and replace to insert a progressive number in Perl?

Tags: perl, replace

I am sorry, if this question sounds stupid, but I have searched a lot and by now I am working the better part of a day on a rather trivial task.

I need to insert progressively numbered IDs into a text file. There are already Placeholders in the file, so that I would tend to work with search and replace. The best I could do was the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $counter = 1;
my $oldID = "docID=\"";
my $newID = "docID=\"14$counter"; #should the return the IDs 141, 142, 143 ...

open (FILE, "file.txt") || die $!;
@content = <FILE>;

foreach (@content){
s/$oldID/$newID/;
$counter++;
}

open (OUT, ">file_ID.txt") || die $!;
print OUT @content;
close OUT;
close(FILE);

print = "$counter" #this is to test if the counter is working.
```

this finds and replaces the docID="". Unfortunaately it replaces all of the occurences of docID with 141.

I would suppose that it doesn't work because all the occurences get replaced all at once and the counter never gets a chance to grow larger. This however does not look plausible if I see $counter growing way too large. It is exactly 12 times the number of occurences of docID.

I believe I need to get perl to replace only one occurence of docID, then raise the counter and then do this in a loop until the end of the document.

Could anyone help me out please? I would be very grateful

Thx

Iulius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open my $in, '<', 'file.txt' or die "$! opening input";
open my $out, '>', 'file_ID.txt' or die "$! opening output";

my $counter = 141;

while (<$in>) {
    s/docID="/q{docID="} . $counter++ /eg;
    print $out $_;
}
```

Uses `s///e` to replace and increment the counter as instances are found, and processes the file line-by-line instead of reading it all into memory and writing it all back out again, because there's no real reason to do that.

Answer (score 2):

perl regexps support "eval" such that you can do:

```
s/$oldId/"docid=\"" . $newId++ . "\""/e
```

where the /e is the eval part that evals the replacement every call.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you can move the $newID variable inside the for loop :

```
foreach (@content){
    my $newID = "docID=\"14$counter";
    s/$oldID/$newID/;
    $counter++;
}
```